# How to validate that username does not start with certain string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

One of the variables in a User model is `username`. I would like to reserve usernames starting with "vondel" for something else. Therefore, I would like to make it invalid for a `username` to start with "vondel". How can I do this?

Below is my attempt to set the validations on `username`. However, generating a `username` that starts with "vondel" is still possible and generates no error message. Is there a way to do this with a regular expression?

```
before_save :downcase_username        # Method that converts username to all downcase.
VALID_USERNAME_REGEX = /\A[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\z/i
validates :username, presence: true,
                     length: { in: 6..15 },
                     format: { with: VALID_USERNAME_REGEX },
                     uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
validate :vondel_not_allowed

private 
  def vondel_not_allowed
    if username == "vondel*"
      errors.add(:username, "Username cannot start with 'vondel'")
    end
  end
```

Comment: Blacklisting is a slippery slope. What about strings starting with `v0ndel`, `\/ondel`, `Vond3l`...? When you try to restrict people, there are some who take it as a challenge to beat your algorithm. And people are a lot more inventive in ways to circumvent your code than you are going to be in writing code to intercept them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straightforward way is to use the `starts_with?` method:

```
test_string = "vondelfoo"
test_string.starts_with?("vondel") # => true
```

Just as an aside, I recommend you learn how to do this with a regex. Regexes are an invaluable tool, and you should definitely learn how to use them.

Also a tip - I've heard [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) to be a good tool for getting started with Ruby regular expressions.

**edit**

[the Tin Man](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128421/the-tin-man) brings up a good point - Regexps are a powerful but an overly complex solution for this problem. Although I highly recommend you learn how to use them, you should prefer the straightforward and simple solution here.

Comment: A Regular Expression, *in the right place, and correctly written*, is an invaluable tool. Incorrectly written or used when other methods are more sensible, understandable or maintainable, is a nightmare or CPU-time burner. `starts_with?` will run circles around a regular expression because it's designed to do one thing, see if the string starts with the sub-string; Regular expressions are generalized and as a result suffer in readability and speed. Regex are cool when used correctly, but they're not a universal solution.

Comment: Wrap the string to lower-case and compare against the lower-case version of the target, otherwise string-case differences will result in failures to match: `'Foo'.start_with?('foo') # => false` vs. `'Foo'.downcase.start_with?('foo') # => true`

Answer (score 1):

Just change the condition in your `vondel_not_allowed` method to:

```
def vondel_not_allowed
  if username.start_with?('vondel')
    errors.add(:username, "cannot start with 'vondel'")
  end
end
```